# How to use a Laravel Collection as both object and array?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am doing this:

`$product = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection($product_array);`

But it works as an array not as an object like `$product->subscription` won't work, but `$product['subscription']` would work.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: laravel 4.2 .......@lowerends

Answer (score 2):

You can use collections like this in an object-oriented way:

```
$product->get('subscription');
```

Comment: No but in my code, I have an eloquent object being used as array and object, so I now have a custom array. I want it to behave like that too..so I don't have to replace my existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.setflags.php) with the `ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS` flag to

```
$api = new \ArrayObject(collect([
   'api_version' => 1,
   'facebook_id' => 1,
]),2)

echo $api->facebook_id; // ouputs 1
```

Notice the `2` is just shorthand for `ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS` to mask the uglyness.

There must be another way and we're just missing something. I'm on Laravel 5.4 and trying to use this in a method to take either `$request` or something like `$api` from the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = (object) $product_array;
$product->subscription;
```

Example :

```
$product_arr = [ 
   'name' => 'bag',
   'qty' => 4,
];

$product = (object) $product_arr;
$product->name; // result = bag
```

Comment: If you are not sure if something is a correct solution, please test it before posting it. That way you will have both learned something (whether it works or not, and ideally why it does so), and you will be able to pass it forward better. Ideally you will also be able to explain why it works and what was the problem in the original question.